# Perl: How to reference to an array?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a program here that will allow user to enter in words that will be used as filenames later on. The user's input is inserted into an array. I then create a simple menu asking what the user wants to do with the "filename": create, reame, copy, and delete. Using subroutines, I believe I've successfully executed the code. However, I am having trouble trying to reference the array element. 
In short, how do I create, rename, copy, and delete the filenames that are saved in the array? The issues I cant resolve are asterisked

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy qw/copy/;

my $new;
my $old;
my $file;

print "Enter number of lines\n";
chomp(my $n = <STDIN>);

my @lines;
print "Enter some words!\n";
for (1..$n) {

chomp(my $input = <STDIN>);
#will add the user input at the beginning of the array
push @lines, $input;
}
print "@lines\n";

#create a menu
my $in = '';
print "1. Create\n2. Rename\n3. Copy\n4. Delete\n5. Quit\n";
while ($in ne "quit")
{
  print "\nEnter the your choice:\n";
    chomp($in = <STDIN>);
  print "For which file do you want to $in?\n";
  print "@lines\n";
  **#I need to reference the array here***********************

  if ($in eq "create") {
***How to create the file that the user inputted?*****************
    &createFile;
    print "\nFile has been created\n";
  }
  elsif ($in eq "rename") {
    #print "Enter the old name\n";
     # chomp($old = <STDIN>);
#*********refer to array of FILES*********************
    print "Enter the new name for this file!\n";
      chomp($new = <STDIN>);
    &renameFile;
    print "File has successfully been renamed.";
  }
  elsif ($in eq "copy") {
#********file and array refering***************************
    &copyFile;
    print "Hopefully, the file has beed copied!";
  }
  elsif ($in eq "delete") {
#******refer to file from user*******************
    &deleteFile;
    print "Deleted";
  }
}



#create subroutine
sub createFile {
  open('>' .*****issue here too**) or die "\nCannot create";
}

sub renameFile {
  rename ($old, $new);
}

sub copyFile {
  copy $old, $new;
}

sub deleteFile {
  #unlink *****************************
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First line is $line[0], second is $line[1] and so on...

You can get user choice like this:

```
   $line[$in]
```

Answer (score -1):

About how to refer to perl data structures see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23649118/perl-return-hash-from-subroutine/35792849#35792849)

```
$lines[0]; #First line
$lines[1]; #Second line
$array = \@lines; # Get reference to the list of lines
$array->[0]; #First line
$array->[1]; #Second line
```

to create file and put data into just use:

```
open $fh, '>filename';
print $fh @lines;
print $fh @$array; # ... or same for reference
```

Notice lack of coma after `$fh`