# Modify mutidimensional hash passed by reference in PERL

Tags: perl, caching, hash

I'm trying to do a function in Perl (see below) able verify the existence of each word in the hash (%emailWords) over the hash (%cache). If the word from %emailWords is not in the %cache but the method belongsTo returns true %cache hashmap must be updated with the new $word. However, altough I pass the %cache hashmap as reference, the value outside the function is empty.

```
sub computeConceptsUntilLevel{

    my $hashRef = shift;
    my $wordnetRef = shift;
    my $cacheRef = shift;
    my $deepLevel = shift;

    my %emailWords = %{$hashRef};
    my @conceptsArray = @{$wordnetRef};
    my %cache = %{$cacheRef};

    my @toret = ();

    for (my $i=0;$i<$deepLevel;$i++){
        my %conceptsMap = ();
        foreach my $concept (@{$conceptsArray[$i]}){
            foreach my $word (keys %emailWords) {
                print "[$i]->Palabra: $word - Concepto: $concept\n";
                if (wordHasConcept(\%cache,$word,$concept,$i)){
                    push @{$conceptsMap{$concept}}, $word;
                }else{
                    if (defined($word) and belongsTo($word,$concept)){
                        push @{$conceptsMap{$concept}}, $word;
                        push @{$cache{$word}{$i}}, $concept;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $toret[$i] = \%conceptsMap;
    }
    return @toret;
}
```

Inside the function the %cache looks like:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'cat' => {
                     '1' => [
                              'physical_entity#n#1'
                            ],
                     '0' => [
                              'entity#n#1'
                            ]
                   },
          'duck' => {
                      '1' => [
                               'physical_entity#n#1'
                             ],
                      '0' => [
                               'entity#n#1'
                             ]
                    }
        };
```

But outside is $VAR1={}.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you didn't pass a hash by reference; you passed a reference to a hash.

While `$VAR1`, `$_[2]` and `$cacheref` all reference the same hash, it's not `%cache`. Changing `%cache` won't affect the hash referenced by those (though changing variables referenced by values of `%cache` may change variables referenced by values of `%$cacheref`).

Simplest solution: Stop doing all those wasteful copies!

```
sub computeConceptsUntilLevel{

    my $emailWords    = shift;
    my $conceptsArray = shift;
    my $cache         = shift;
    my $deepLevel     = shift;

    my @toret = ();

    for (my $i=0;$i<$deepLevel;$i++){
        my %conceptsMap = ();
        foreach my $concept (@{$conceptsArray->[$i]}){
            foreach my $word (keys %$emailWords) {
                print "[$i]->Palabra: $word - Concepto: $concept\n";
                if (wordHasConcept($cache,$word,$concept,$i)){
                    push @{$conceptsMap{$concept}}, $word;
                }else{
                    if (defined($word) and belongsTo($word,$concept)){
                        push @{$conceptsMap{$concept}}, $word;
                        push @{$cache->{$word}{$i}}, $concept;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $toret[$i] = \%conceptsMap;
    }
    return @toret;
}
```

---

If you want to allow

```
computeConceptsUntilLevel(..., ..., my $cache, ...)
```

Change

```
my $cache = shift;
```

to

```
my $cache = ( shift //= {} );
```

This is possible because arguments are (always) passed by reference in Perl.

---

```
for my $i (0 .. $deepLevel-1)
```

is clearer and more efficient than

```
for (my $i=0;$i<$deepLevel;$i++){
```

---

```
push @toret, \%conceptsMap;
```

is clearer than

```
$toret[$i] = \%conceptsMap;
```

---

```
my @toret;
my %conceptsMap;
```

are less wasteful and cluttered versions of

```
my @toret = ();
my %conceptsMap = ();
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand better how to work with perl data structures look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35792849/4632019)

The problem in your program lives here:

```
my %cache = %{$cacheRef};
```

Here you create copy of cache inside your sub. So any keys you add at this sub will live only at %cache and %$cacheRef will intact.

In modern perl you may do:

```
my \%cache = $cacheRef;
```

This will alias %cache to $cacheRef.
Or do some replaces in your code:

1. Remove this `my %cache = %{$cacheRef};`
2. Instead of `\%cache` use `$cacheRef`
3. Instead of `$cache{$word}{$i}` use `$cacheRef->{$word}{$i}`
   `\%cache`